# PyGis: How to enable and disable raster layers with Python?

Tags: python, raster, ppygis

How to enable and disable raster layers with Python? It should be a solution without selecting the layers before turn them off or on. I could find some code snippets for vector layers, but not for raster layers.

Comment: Add the code you tried with or your question will get closed.

Comment: Your title has "PyGis" (which only exists as an obscure pypi 0.1.3 package), the question is tagged `ppygis` (which is a Psycopg extension), and the answers are for PyQGIS.  Please [Edit] the question to specify what exact software you are asking about, and include your code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the same for vector and raster layers. But you can add an if statement to only check/uncheck raster layers:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for c in root.children():
    if isinstance(c.layer(), QgsRasterLayer):
        c.setItemVisibilityChecked(True) #Or False
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where I have to insert the layername that should be enabled or disabled. Lats say "Testlayer". Sorry Im a beginner;-)

Comment: Change if line to for example: `if isinstance(c.layer(), QgsRasterLayer) and c.layer().name() in (('somelayer', 'someotherlayer')):`

Answer (score 1):

The ideal would be something as simple as a mapLayer method, like setVisible(), but it does not exist :).

But it is not very complicated, **you can do it**, on raster and vector layers with the `setItemVisibility` method from `QgsLayerTreeRoot`

```
pry= QgsProject.instance() #first i get the project
lc= list(pry.mapLayers().values()) #created a list of all the layers

#I can work with the layer or its id
idLayer= lc[0].id() #I get the id of the first layer
layer= lc[0] #I get the firts layer

pry.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(id).setItemVisibilityChecked(True) #visible
pry.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer).setItemVisibilityChecked(False) #not visible
```